# Odd function pointer segmentation fault

Tags: c++, function, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

I have to find the value of *x* such that *f(x)=C*, where *f* is a monotonically increasing function over the interval *[a,b]*. It has to have a logarithmic complexity so I've made this function which I believe to be correct:

```cpp
double search(double a, double b, double c, double (*f)(double x)) {
    double pivot;
    do {
        pivot = abs((a-b)/2);
        if (abs((*f)(pivot) - c) < 0.001) { //f(x) == c
            return pivot;
        } else if ((*f)(pivot) > c) {
            b = pivot;
        } else {
            a = pivot;
        }
    } while (abs(a-b) != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

which works whenever I call it like this:

```cpp
int main(void) {
    double a = 0.0, b = 10.0, c = 5.0;

    cout << search(a, b, c, func1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but if I change it to this (the value of `b`):

```cpp
int main(void) {
    double a = 0.0, b = 100.0, c = 5.0;

    cout << search(a, b, c, func1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault when the function is called. What is going wrong here?
(I can see that the program crashes when the function is called when I use the VSCode debugger. Otherwise, when I just compile and run it, it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop or something i.e. it doesn't throw the segmentation fault error).

If needed, `func1` simply does `return 2 * x`.

EDIT:

Here's the full `.cpp` file if someone needs it to reproduce:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double func1(double x) {
    return 2 * x;
}

double func2(double x) {
    return x + 0.5;
}

double search(double a, double b, double c, double (*f)(double x)) {
    double pivot;
    do {
        pivot = abs((b-a)/2);
        if (abs((*f)(pivot) - c) < 0.1) { //f(x) == c
            return pivot;
        } else if ((*f)(pivot) > c) {
            b = pivot;
        } else {
            a = pivot;
        }
    } while (abs(b-a) != 0);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    double a = 0.0, b = 10.0, c = 5.0;

    cout << search(a, b, c, &func1) << endl;
    cout << search(a, b, c, func1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

where changing the value of b to 100.0 will cause the fault to occur.

Comment: a [mcve] is needed to reproduce the crash

Comment: Shouldn't it be abs(f(pivot) - c)  instead of abs((*f)(pivot) - c). Other then that what does func look like because if I make one up the whole code is stuck in an infinite loop (calculation doesn't converge). So yes a minimal reproducible example would be nice

Comment: for such iterative computations you should alsways count the number of iterations and break when it gets too high. This helps for testing and debugging. Instead of a crash you could produce some informative output

Comment: For the infinite loop, you can just step through the debugger to see why it's stuck. (For example, if `a` or `b` is negative, or if the slope of `f` is too high.)

Answer (score 2):

`pivot = abs((a-b)/2);` is wrong it as it computes half of the distance from *a* to *b* not the middle point of them, use:

```
pivot = abs((a-b)/2)+a; // provided that *a* is less than *b*
```

Comment: This is the case. I am an idiot, thank you very much

Comment: Make that `pivot = (a+b)/2` and you don't have to worry which of the two is larger.